# HTTPS upload to S3 using boto?

Tags: python, https, amazon-s3, boto

There is a class "`boto.s3.connection`" in which I can make a connection to S3:

```
b = s3conection(aws_id, aws_secret_key)
b.get_bucket(bucket)
```

With this I can clearly use `set_contents_from_filename` or `set_contents_from_file`.

There is another call `build_post_form_args`. I can set the connection type here as HTTPS, but what do I do next if I use this call instead of the previous?

I am unable to figure out how it all fits in with `set_contents_from_filename` or `set_contents_from_file`. A small hint would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S3 service provides a feature that allows you to upload a file directly to an S3 bucket from an HTML form.  You can find more details about this feature [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html).  The `build_post_form_args` is a helper function that creates the signed HTML form data that must be placed in the HTML form to allow this direct upload to S3.

Unless you are interesting in doing uploads from within a browser, this function is not really useful or relevant.

Comment: Thanks,I am not using browser to upload. it's a desktop software which pushes files to s3, i needed to secure the contents with "https" so that the data which i am sending to cloud can be secured.

Comment: The boto library uses HTTPS by default and, from version 2.6.0 onwards, also does SSL Certificate Validation by default.